# Increase number with button and add text vb2010

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = Val(Label1.Text) + 1
End Sub
```

When the button is pressed, the value on the label increases by 1.
How do I make it put a text after the value?
Example: The value is "0" and when the button is pressed, the label changes to "1 post", press again "2 posts", again "3 posts"...

Answer (score 1):

Your codes are quite right to increase and show values in a label control. **Val()** function always returns the first appeared numerical part of an alphanumeric string. If **Label1** holds **"1 Post"** then **Val(Label1.Text)** always returns **1**. The codes should be

```html
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    

    If (Val(Label1.Text) + 1)=1 then
        Label1.Text = (Val(Label1.Text) + 1) & " Post"
    ElseIf
        Label1.Text = (Val(Label1.Text) + 1) & " Posts"
    Endif
End Sub
```

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your setting label's text = `0` in the form load

create a function like below

```
Private Sub label_posts(ByVal lbl As Label)
        With lbl 
            If Val(.Text) = 0 Then
                .Text = Val(.Text) + 1 & " Post"
            Else
                .Text = Val(.Text) + 1 & " Posts"
            End If
        End With
 End Sub
```

and call this `label_posts` in the button's click event by passing the label's name with it.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    label_posts(Label1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess your setting label's text = 0 in the form load

No need to assign label's text = 0. If value of the label's Text Property is Blank or It has no Numerical part, Val() function always returns 0. So no need to assign to the value 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim x as Integer

x += 1;

Label1.Text = x.ToString();
```

Comment: This does not increment the value in the label or append the string "post" or "posts".